# $_FILES['input']['type'] not working?

Tags: php, file-upload, jpeg

Here is my code:

```
if ( $_FILES['photo']['type'] != "image/jpeg" )
    echo "You attempted to upload a file of type: " . $_FILES['photo']['type'] . " ... The file must be a JPEG.";
```

As you can see... my code is checking to see whether or not the file type is a JPEG... if it is, it continues, else, it does not.

But even though the type IS a JPEG, I keep getting the echo that it's not:

"You attempted to upload a file of type: image/jpeg ... The file must be a JPEG."

There is just no way that that echo statement should ever be executed unless the file was NOT a JPEG.

Comment: What is your JPEG's file type? What does your script echo when you try? I don't see the if/else constraint in your code sample.

Comment: What is my JPEG file type? ... JPEG? ... The only rule that matter is the `!=` ... and that echo is being executed even though it IS a JPEG.

Comment: but your update shows you are not uploading a image/jpeg but rather a text/jpeg. I think the real question here is what on earth is a text/jpeg

Comment: Well as you can see, it's "text/jpeg" and not "image/jpeg". Either your server or your browser are submitting the wrong mime type. Alternatively to the string file type checking, try processing the image file with [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: @KaiQing ASCII art in jpeg? ;)

Comment: I did a basic google search cause I've never heard of a text/jpeg - though I wish peehaa's explanation was reality - and found absolutely nothing. I don't know what to suggest regarding this odd case but to try with a different image to make sure there's no weird corruption in the test file you're currently using.

Comment: Yeah, I just dont get it. There has to be a better way to test whether or not a file is of type JPEG or not

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust the mime types. If you want to be pretty sure, open the file, read the first couple of bytes, and check if it's a JPEG file header.

If you want to be really really sure, use [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) to actually load the jpeg file. If this fails, then it's apparently not a real jpeg file, no matter what mime types and file headers tell you. Note, that you need to have [`GD`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) available to use this function.

Comment: What's a failsafe way to read the file header? This has got to work no matter what browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple code for file upload. It actually checks file extension, not mime type. The code is below -

```
function getFileExtention($name) {
    $split = explode('.',$name);
    $splitCount = count($split) - 1;
    return strtolower($split[$splitCount]);
}

if(getFileExtention($_FILES['input']['name'] != "jpg" && getFileExtention($_FILES['input']['name'] != "jpeg") {
  echo "You attempted to upload a file of type: " . $_FILES['photo']['type'] . " ... The file must be a JPEG.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unsafe to rely on the mime-type or the filename given in the `$_FILES` array, as they are given by the browser.

Use `finfo_file` instead, which will check on the server-side, based on the header/content of the file:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['input']['tmp_name']);
if ($mimeType != "image/jpeg") {
    echo "You attempted to upload a file of type: " . $mimeType . " ... The file must be a JPEG.";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use `$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["$key"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Information directly from PHP's api.